# How to get an Array of Meshes

Tags: lua, gideros

```
myMesh = {}
myMesh[0].x = 30
```

Nope... doesn't work.

```
myMesh = Mesh.new{}
myMesh[0].x = 30
```

Nope... no go.

An array of meshes should be possible, but I don't know how. Can someone help? Thanks

*Edit:*
Thanks for your responses. Pardon me for this stupid mistake. I just realized, "What nonsense are you doing J?" I really wanted an array of vertices of the mesh, so that I can use loops to manipulate them. Sorry about that... although it didn't hurt to learn how to get an array of meshes.

So I figured it out, because I was sure I did this before, when I used gml.

```
ptx = {}; pty = {}; ptz = {} 
ptx[1] = myMesh.x; pty[1] = myMesh.y; ptz[1] = myMesh.z;
```

Thanks for the help though. I also learned that lua doesn't use index 0

*Edit:* Wait. That doesn't work either does it?

Well for now this gives no error, so I'll see if it does what I want.

```
pMesh = {}
 for m=1, 6 do
    pMesh[m] = Mesh.new()
 end

pMesh[1].x = 0; pMesh[1].y = 0; pMesh[1].z = 0
```

Thanks guys. If you have any other suggestions, I'm all ears.

Comment: besides the Lua syntax errors, this doesn't make sense. why would a mesh have an x coordinate? what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myMesh = {}
myMesh[0].x = 30
```

Will cause an error for indexing a `nil` value.

`myMesh = {}` creates an empty Lua table.

doing `myMesh[0].x` is not allowed because there is no `myMesh[0]`.
First you have to insert a table element at index 0.

```
myMesh = {}
myMesh[0] = Mesh.new(true)
myMesh[0].x = 30
```

myMesh is a stupid name for an array of meshes as it suggests it's just a single mesh.
Also in Lua we usually start with index 1 which will makes things a bit easier using Lua's standard table tools.
I'm not sure if

```
mesh = Mesh.new()
mesh.x = 30
```

is actually ok. Why would a mesh have an x coordinate? This is not listed in Mesh's properties in the manual.

Usually you would create a Mesh with multiple points And if you want an array of multiple meshes you would simply put those meshes into a table unless there is a particular user data type for this.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know guys know - using an array of meshes to store the vertex position worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myMesh = {}
myMesh[0]= Mesh.new{}
myMesh[0].x = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize as a table and columns and rows:

```
myMesh = {}
myMesh[0] = {}
myMesh[0].x=30
```

or

```
myMesh = { [0]={} }
myMesh[0].x=30
```